# Trigger function when no match found in QCompleter

Tags: python, pyside6, qcompleter

I am using a QCompleter with a list of countries on a QLineEdit. I am getting the selected country name when match found. But I want to trigger a function when no match is found.

```
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QCompleter, QLineEdit

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("My Widget")
        self.resize(200, 100)

        self.lis = ['Germany','Russia','France', 'Norway' ,'India' ,'nepal']
        self.completer = QCompleter(self.lis)
        self.completer.setCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)

        self.edit = QLineEdit()
        self.edit.setCompleter(self.completer)
        self.completer.activated.connect(self.on_completer_activated)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.edit)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def on_completer_activated(self, text):
        print(text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication()
    widget = MyWidget()
    widget.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: I think `QLineEdit` should have `event` to execute function when it change content in `QLineEdit` - and you could use it to check what you have in `QLineEdit` and compare with `self.lis` to see if there wasn't matches. Maybe `QCompleter` also generates some events.

Comment: `self.edit.textEdited.connect(self.on_completer_activated)`

Comment: Unfortunately, QCompleter doesn't seem to offer any reliable way to check whether a given string can be completed. Methods like `completionCount` and `currentCompletion` return invalid results when the string has one or zero characters.